# Extract when last character of a word is number Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column with values that contain 4 characters. The last character can be a letter or a number.

```
Column name: testing
EXPA
FTSA
HUTS
JUF8
GTD9
```

In my `WHERE` clause I would like to filter on my column 'testing' to only display the values where the last character is a number
Hence the output in this case would be:

```
Output
JUF8
GTD9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(jarring chord!)

There is only ONE way to do this - use `REGEXP_INSTR`:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'EXPA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'FTSA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'HUTS' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'JUF8' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'GTD9' AS TESTING FROM DUAL)
SELECT TESTING
  FROM cteData
  WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(TESTING, '[0-9]$') > 0;
```

Or you can use `SUBSTR`...

(jarring chord!)

Ah-ha! There are only TWO ways to do this:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'EXPA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'FTSA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'HUTS' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'JUF8' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'GTD9' AS TESTING FROM DUAL)
SELECT TESTING
  FROM cteData
  WHERE SUBSTR(TESTING, -1) IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
```

Or you can use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`...oh, damn! I'll just go out and come in again, shall I?

(jarring chord!)

Ah-ha! There are THREE ways to do this:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'EXPA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'FTSA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'HUTS' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'JUF8' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'GTD9' AS TESTING FROM DUAL)
SELECT TESTING
  FROM cteData
  WHERE INSTR('0123456789', SUBSTR(TESTING, -1)) > 0;
```

Or you can use `SUBSTR` and `TRANSLATE`...

(jarring chord!)

HAH-HAH!!! THERE ARE MANY AND DIVERSE WAYS TO ACCOMPLISH YOUR GOAL! AMONG THEM ARE - `REGEXP_LIKE`, `SUBSTR` by itself, `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`, **AND** `TRANSLATE` AND `SUBSTR`:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'EXPA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'FTSA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'HUTS' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'JUF8' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'GTD9' AS TESTING FROM DUAL)
SELECT TESTING
  FROM cteData
  WHERE TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(TESTING, -1),
                  '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                  '0123456789') IS NOT NULL;
```

But I certainly didn't expect the Spanish Inquisition...

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10bad528ce04de407ee9cc373c3b4730)

Comment: It's nice to see that you were having a good time answering this :)

Comment: Better watch out. I've got a comfy chair and a soft pillow AND I'M NOT AFRAID TO USE THEM!!!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

With [`regexp_like()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php):

```
select testing
from tablename
where regexp_like(testing, '[0-9]$')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0639ba9e698bf5656de3ef5d34de4a07).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12c R2 or later, you can try with [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'EXPA' AS TESTING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'FTSA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'HUTS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'JUF8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'GTD9' FROM DUAL)
SELECT TESTING
  FROM cteData
  WHERE validate_conversion(substr(testing,-1) as integer) =1;
```

Result:

[image]